# Can not resolve reference Plugin.Permissions

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-permissions

I get this error when use of Plugin.Permissions in xamarin.forms:

Can not resolve reference: Plugin.Permissions, referenced by MyProject. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Plugin.Permissions, or remove the reference to MyProject.  MyProject.Android

but I added plugin.permission in all Projects (Forms, android, ios)

Comment: Check your .csproj file, do you really add them?
Also you can try to reinstall this nuget package.

Comment: I tried this, but it does'nt work!

Comment: I would suggest you flush and fill this nuget package and it should work again

Comment: Are you trying to install fresh this plugin? Debug or Release version? Do you have any other plugins that you recently updated ?

Comment: I tried all of this works. @BrunoCaceiro and G.hakim. none of them work!

Comment: And you get no error in the console?

Comment: Hi, also can show image to help find problem.When addde NuGet Package , try to restart project to check whether it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this method in MainActivity:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

and added after base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState) below line:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainService));
        StartService(intent);
        layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Layout.AlertActivity);
        Log.Debug("StartService", "DemoService started");

        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;


        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //this line added
        Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this,
savedInstanceState);

        Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

Now, everything works fine!
thanks for your helps!